# Is it time saving for loading a saved tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow

The question is,I cannot make my computer work for my tensorflow-gpu on ubuntu system. Because NVIDIA driver cannot be installed on ubuntu.So I run tensorflow-gpu on Windows10,but it doesnot support tensorflow-serving.
I know Docker can help me to do it,and i really installed it,but just tensorflow-cpu.That would be very slowly if I just run tensorflow-cpu version.
In case that,I came up with a thought that I install two tensorflow,one is GPU version and on system,the other is CPU version on Docker.GPU version for training and save a model,then CPU version loading the saved model.
What I want to know is does this way work,and is it time saving?Or put it simply,does it take less time than just run tensorflow-cpu version on Docker?

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow GPU with NVIDIA GPUs on Ubuntu is supported, and there are drivers available. Check [this tutorial.](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux)

Comment: Thanks Jan.I know technically NVIDIA driver can be installed on Ubuntu,and there are lots of tutorials for installing.But I just cannot make it work. And I was unfamiliar with Ubuntu system, so I came up with that thought.